# Custom builds of jQueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, git, node.js, jquery-ui

I just created a custom build of jQuery, and I slimmed down the library to only include the parts that I need. I did this by following the instructions documented on the jQuery repo hosted on GitHub. It basically uses node.js, npm, git, and grunt, and you're able to exclude parts of the API all in command line, and make a build.

Now I need to do the same thing with jQueryUI, but I don't see such instructions in their documentation. Does anyone know if this can be done the same way? What's the easiest way to slim down a jQueryUI library, and customize it specifically according to my needs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you want to slim down the jQueryUI? which part of its features you want to keep and which version of jQuery do you use?

Comment: @MehranHatami: I want to remove whatever's not being used. Trying to reduce all overhead, even minor overhead...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it with your grunt build, just add some params to your config. Example:

`grunt custom:-ajax,-css,-dimensions,-effects,-offset`

or modify the necessary Gruntfile.js (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/Gruntfile.js)

Comment: That's how it works with jQuery. Can I do this with jQueryUI too?

Comment: The link I gave you is for jQuery UI.

Comment: Task "custom" is not available for jquery-ui

Answer (score 0):

To build a custom version of jQuery UI from an NPM package, you have to use `requirejs`. Your grunt config will look something like this:

```
    requirejs: {
        jqueryui: {
            options: {
                expand: true,
                baseUrl: '<%= nodeModules %>/jquery-ui/',
                paths: {
                    jquery: './external/jquery/jquery',
                    external: './external/',
                },
                optimize: 'none',
                findNestedDependencies: true,
                skipModuleInsertion: true,
                exclude: ['jquery'],
                include:
                    grunt.file.expand(
                    {
                        cwd: path.resolve(appConfig.nodeModules + '/jquery-ui/'),
                    },
                    [
                        'ui/effect.js',
                        'ui/effects/*.js',
                        'list of files to include in your build',
                    ]),
                out: '<%= www %>/js/jquery-ui.js',
            },
        },
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

go to this [page](http://jqueryui.com/download/) and select your favorite features, then download it as a custom build.